# Filtering by group and keeping all instances where condition is met

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, grouping

I found an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29630045/how-to-filter-with-dplyr-for-all-values-of-a-group-if-variable-limit-is-reache) of something similar

Essentially, I need to keep all items of a group where a user equal to some factor.

For example here is my initial data frame.

```
data <- data.frame(user = c("a","a",'b',"b",'c',"c","a","a","a","d","d","d"), 
                   invoiceNum =c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2))
```

I need to keep all invoices which have user `d`.

The output would look like:

```
  user invoiceNum
1    a          2
2    a          2
3    a          2
4    d          2
5    d          2
6    d          2
```

I tried writing the following code but it does not work and gives me the following

```
data%>% group_by(invoiceNum)%>%dplyr::filter(user == "d")


    user invoiceNum
  <fctr>      <dbl>
1      d          2
2      d          2
3      d          2
```

Comment: Try `data %>% group_by(invoiceNum) %>% filter(any(user == "d"))`

Comment: you answered this first. If you want you can submit it as an answer and I will select it. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in `base` R:

```
data[data$invoiceNum %in% unique(data[data$user=="d",]$invoiceNum),]

#   user invoiceNum
#7     a          2
#8     a          2
#9     a          2
#10    d          2
#11    d          2
#12    d          2
```

So you first find those `invoiceNum` in which user `d` is appeared

- `unique(data[data$user=="d",]$invoiceNum)`

and then filter out the rows with those extracted `invoiceNum`.

---

**EDIT**

In case you want to do the same for multiple users:

```
usr <- c("d", "a")
data[data$invoiceNum %in% unique(data[data$user %in% usr,]$invoiceNum),]
```

Comment: How would i modify this to include multiple users?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `%in%`

```
data %>%
     group_by(invoiceNum) %>%
     filter('d' %in% user)
#    user invoiceNum
#  <fctr>      <dbl>
#1      a          2
#2      a          2
#3      a          2
#4      d          2
#5      d          2
#6      d          2
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How would the code be if I wanted to filter on multiple users. I tried` data %>%
  group_by(invoiceNum) %>%
  filter(c("a","d") %in% user) `but does not work

Comment: Using `c("a","d")` is looking for (a,d) as the user. You should use `|` for OR. E.g. `filter('d' %in% user | 'a' %in% user)` . The base R solution is probably easier if you want to expand this list