# Subset with all values for a variable in R

Tags: r, filter, tidyr

I have a Data Frame with a variable with different values for another variable.
Like this:
 [DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5uzv.png)

So, I need a subset when the value of S contain all the possible values of B. In this example, el subset is conformed by S = a and S = b:

[Subset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPzfZ.png)

Any idea? Thanks!!

Comment: I think you have a typo, it should be `S=a and S = d` (based on the image showed)

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can easily help with. That includes a sample of data (not pictures of it) and whatever code you've tried so far. Also is quite similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/46964794/5325862

Comment: Reopened the dupe tag as it is not a duplicate of this post

Answer (score -1):

An option would be to group by 'S' and `filter` the rows having `all` the `unique` values of the column 'B' `%in%` 'B'

```
library(dplyr)
un1 <- unique(df1$B)
df1 %>%
    group_by(S) %>%
    filter(all(un1 %in% B))
# A tibble: 8 x 2
# Groups:   S [2]
#  S         B
#  <fct> <dbl>
#1 a         1
#2 a         2
#3 a         3
#4 a         4
#5 d         1
#6 d         2
#7 d         3
#8 d         4
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .SD[all(un1 %in% B)], S]
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df1[with(df1, ave(B, S, FUN = function(x) all(un1 %in% x)) == 1),]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(S = rep(letters[1:4], c(4, 3, 2, 4)),
          B = c(1:4, c(1, 3, 4), 1:2, 1:4))
```